# how to fix Out of memory in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I experience a problem with memory limit in wordpress :
When I try to uplod an image, the site crashes and I find that in the logs :

[31-Oct-2020 16:28:45 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 2097152) (tried to allocate 65536 bytes) in /var/www/webroot/ROOT/wp-content/plugins/jetpack/class.jetpack-plan.php on line 233

[31-Oct-2020 16:28:45 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 2097152) (tried to allocate 65536 bytes) in /var/www/webroot/ROOT/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/admin/class-wc-admin-settings.php on line 54

[31-Oct-2020 16:28:45 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 2097152) (tried to allocate 65536 bytes) in /var/www/webroot/ROOT/wp-content/plugins/jetpack/class.jetpack-plan.php on line 233

[31-Oct-2020 16:28:52 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 2097152) (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /var/www/webroot/ROOT/wp-includes/pomo/mo.php on line 323

[31-Oct-2020 16:28:52 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 2097152) (tried to allocate 135168 bytes) in /var/www/webroot/ROOT/wp-includes/pomo/streams.php on line 118

[31-Oct-2020 16:28:57 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 2097152) (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in /var/www/webroot/ROOT/wp-includes/pomo/mo.php on line 315

[31-Oct-2020 16:28:57 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 2097152) (tried to allocate 135168 bytes) in /var/www/webroot/ROOT/wp-includes/pomo/streams.php on line 118

[31-Oct-2020 16:28:59 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 2097152) (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /var/www/webroot/ROOT/wp-includes/pomo/mo.php on line 323

[31-Oct-2020 16:28:59 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 2097152) (tried to allocate 135168 bytes) in /var/www/webroot/ROOT/wp-includes/pomo/streams.php on line 118

[31-Oct-2020 16:29:04 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 2097152) (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /var/www/webroot/ROOT/wp-includes/pomo/mo.php on line 323

[31-Oct-2020 16:29:04 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 2097152) (tried to allocate 135168 bytes) in /var/www/webroot/ROOT/wp-includes/pomo/streams.php on line 118

I've put 1024 as max memory in php.ini, in .htaccess and wp-config. php info says that there is 1024 mb in max memory usage but the problem persists.
What can I do to fix that?

Comment: Try adding this on your apache configuration RLimitMEM max or in the htaccess

Comment: unfortunately, that's change nothing